# How apply margin-top and margin-bottom?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to center this modal in center of the screen leaving some margin on all sides. But margin on top and bottom is not applying!

```
export function Modal() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 z-[60] bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center">
        <div className="bg-background border rounded-lg w-full h-full m-8">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put position relative for that modal parent so that position fixed works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `h-full` class from the container `div`, as it will cover the entire screen height. Also add `max-w-md` to limit the width of the modal. Also include some padding to inner div.

```
export function Modal() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-0 z-[60] flex bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm justify-center items-center">
       <div className="absolute inset-0 flex justify-center items-center">
          <div className="bg-background border rounded-lg w-full max-w-md m-8 p-4">
             <h1>Hello</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```